# Loan for car buy "cash" (third party) or bank loan

Tags: loans

A car salesman offered a lower pricer for the vehicle if you "pay cash". They offered 16,9 for cash but finance was 22. Would it be possible to have a third party give me a loan for the car and offer the salesman that as "cash"? Or will that not be accepted by them or will it look shady? I also have a company that says they can give me the money for the car and then I pay them.

Comment: It will all depend on the interest charged by the 3rd parties. And/or the length of the sales guy's financing.

Comment: While I've heard of discounts for paying with cash, that's a pretty dramatic difference (30% more for financing). I would be cautious dealing with them.

Comment: This story is very unlikely and suspect its an attempt to scam users of this site.  Cash transactions are typically very unprofitable for car dealers.  They make far more money in the fiance office than on the showroom.

Answer (score 5):

The car dealership doesn't care where you get the cash; they care about it becoming their money immediately and with no risk or complications. Any loan or other arrangements you make to raise the cash is Your Problem, not theirs, unless you arrange the loan through them.

Comment: In most cases car dealerships prefer you take a loan or a lease on the car.  They make money off the origination.  Also they can talk you into more options, gap insurance, and extended warranties easier with a loan.

A cash transaction is typically the least profitable way for them to make money.